# Freemarker Loop to write tables

Tags: email, freemarker

This is for email coding.
Seems simple in my head, but I have assigned a set of data to a freemarker variable

```
[#assign LOOP_TAB]${list.creative!'000000'}[/#assign]
```

Where list.creative contains either 1-5

I then want to write the correspsonding amount of simple HTML tables to my template

```
 <!--Begin TEXT BOX-->
                    [#list 0..LOOP_TAB?length-1 as i]
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 20px; color: #000000;"><br>Loop Table Structure.<br><br></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>[/#list]
```

Its sort of working, but im getting two tables by default, and never teh right amount of tables when i test on 2, or 4, or 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rename `LOOP_TAB` to `numberOfTabs`. So, if that's a number, and not a string, then:

```
[#list 1 ..< numberOfTabs!0 as _]
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    ...
  </table>
[/#list]
```

If `numberOfTabs` is a string, and you can't fix the data-model, then use `(numberOfTabs?number)!0` instead of `numberOfTabs!0`.

Some further notes:

- `[#assign LOOP_TAB]${list.creative!'000000'}[/#assign]` can be simply written as `[#assign LOOP_TAB = list.creative!'000000']`. But you don't need this at all, as you have seen.
- `?length` gives the length of the strings in characters, so, it has returned the length of the string in `LOOP_TABS`.
- `from .. to` gives an inclusive range, furthermore `0 .. -1` will give `[0, -1]`, instead of the empty sequence that you wanted. Therefore you need `from ..< to`, which has exclusive end.
- I used `_` as loop variable only to signify that you don't actually read it anywhere. It's not special otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much!
If at all possible, could I pose another wuestion to you @ddekany